# HTML5 canvas ctx.fillText won't do line breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, line, break

I can't seem to be able to add text to a canvas if the text includes "\n". I mean, the line breaks do not show/work.

```
ctxPaint.fillText("s  ome \n \\n <br/> thing", x, y);
```

The above code will draw `"s  ome \n <br/> thing"`, on one line.

Is this a limitation of fillText or am I doing it wrong? the "\n"s are there, and aren't printed, but they don't work either.

Comment: do you want to automatically wrap when reaching the end ? or just to take into consideration the newline chars present in the text ?

Comment: Wrap the text into multiple lines.

Comment: Hi twodordan, does this limitation exist on both chrome and mozilla ?
People often use simple html text that they put over the canvas with a position:absolute for example.
Also you can do two fillText and moving the Y origin of your text for your second lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas - can I somehow use linefeeds in fillText()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478742/html5-canvas-can-i-somehow-use-linefeeds-in-filltext)

Comment: **TL;DR:** Either call `fillText()` multiple times and use your font height to separate, or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText - or, use one of the very complicated "solutions" below that do not use TextMetrics...

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I'm afraid it is a limitation of Canvas' `fillText`. There is no multi-line support. Whats worse, there's no built-in way to measure line height, only width, making doing it yourself even harder!

A lot of people have written their own multi-line support, perhaps the most notable project that has is [Mozilla Skywriter](https://github.com/mozilla/skywriter).

The gist of what you'll need to do is multiple `fillText` calls while adding the height of the text to the y value each time. (measuring the width of M is what the skywriter people do to approximate text, I believe.)

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it would be bothersome... Nice to know about the SKYWRITER, but I'll just "wait" until fillText() is improved. It wasn't a terribly important deal in my case. Hah, no line height, it's like someone did that on purpose. :D

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't hold your breath on fillText() being "improved" to support this, since I get the feeling this is how it is intended to be used (multiple calls & calculating the yOffset yourself). I think a lot of the power with the canvas API is that it separates the lower-level drawing functionality from what you can already do (perform the necessary measurements). Also, you can know the text height simply by providing the text size in pixels; in other words: context.font = "16px Arial"; - you have the height there; the width is the only one that is dynamic.

Comment: [Some additional properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) for `measureText()` have been added which I think could solve the problem. Chrome has a flag to enable them, but other browsers don't... yet!

Comment: @SWdV just to be clear, those have been in the spec for years now, it may be years yet until we have wide enough adoption to use :(

Comment: Maybe `actualBoundingBoxAscent` could be used to measure line height.

Answer (score 114):

If you just want to take care of the newline chars in the text you could simulate it by splitting the text at the newlines and calling multiple times the `fillText()`

Something like http://jsfiddle.net/BaG4J/1/

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c.font = '11px Courier';
    console.log(c);
var txt = 'line 1\nline 2\nthird line..';
var x = 30;
var y = 30;
var lineheight = 15;
var lines = txt.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)
    c.fillText(lines[i], x, y + (i*lineheight) );
```

```css
canvas{background-color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

---

I just made a wrapping proof of concept (*absolute wrap at specified width. No handling words breaking, yet*)
example at http://jsfiddle.net/BaG4J/2/

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c.font = '11px Courier';

var txt = 'this is a very long text to print';

printAt(c, txt, 10, 20, 15, 90 );


function printAt( context , text, x, y, lineHeight, fitWidth)
{
    fitWidth = fitWidth || 0;
    
    if (fitWidth <= 0)
    {
         context.fillText( text, x, y );
        return;
    }
    
    for (var idx = 1; idx <= text.length; idx++)
    {
        var str = text.substr(0, idx);
        console.log(str, context.measureText(str).width, fitWidth);
        if (context.measureText(str).width > fitWidth)
        {
            context.fillText( text.substr(0, idx-1), x, y );
            printAt(context, text.substr(idx-1), x, y + lineHeight, lineHeight,  fitWidth);
            return;
        }
    }
    context.fillText( text, x, y );
}
```

```css
canvas{background-color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

---

And a word-wrapping (*breaking at spaces*) proof of concept.
example at http://jsfiddle.net/BaG4J/5/

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
c.font = '11px Courier';

var txt = 'this is a very long text. Some more to print!';

printAtWordWrap(c, txt, 10, 20, 15, 90 );


function printAtWordWrap( context , text, x, y, lineHeight, fitWidth)
{
    fitWidth = fitWidth || 0;
    
    if (fitWidth <= 0)
    {
        context.fillText( text, x, y );
        return;
    }
    var words = text.split(' ');
    var currentLine = 0;
    var idx = 1;
    while (words.length > 0 && idx <= words.length)
    {
        var str = words.slice(0,idx).join(' ');
        var w = context.measureText(str).width;
        if ( w > fitWidth )
        {
            if (idx==1)
            {
                idx=2;
            }
            context.fillText( words.slice(0,idx-1).join(' '), x, y + (lineHeight*currentLine) );
            currentLine++;
            words = words.splice(idx-1);
            idx = 1;
        }
        else
        {idx++;}
    }
    if  (idx > 0)
        context.fillText( words.join(' '), x, y + (lineHeight*currentLine) );
}
```

```css
canvas{background-color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

---

In the second and third examples i am using the [`measureText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas#measureText%28%29) method which shows how long (*in pixels*) a string will be when printed.

Comment: how to justify the whole long text ?

Comment: If you need a long, justified text, why would you be using a canvas?

Comment: i like the third method

Comment: There doesn't seem any requirement of `if` condition `if(idx > 0)` in the third method. Initial value of `idx` is `1` and it is not decreased anywhere above the `if` condition. The `if` condition will always be `true`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 40):

Maybe coming to this party a bit late, but I found the following tutorial for wrapping text on a canvas perfect.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/

From that I was able to think get multi lines working (sorry Ramirez, yours didn't work for me!).  My complete code to wrap text in a canvas is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     // http: //www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/
     function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
        var cars = text.split("\n");

        for (var ii = 0; ii < cars.length; ii++) {

            var line = "";
            var words = cars[ii].split(" ");

            for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
                var testLine = line + words[n] + " ";
                var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
                var testWidth = metrics.width;

                if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
                    context.fillText(line, x, y);
                    line = words[n] + " ";
                    y += lineHeight;
                }
                else {
                    line = testLine;
                }
            }

            context.fillText(line, x, y);
            y += lineHeight;
        }
     }

     function DrawText() {

         var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
         var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

         context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 600);

         var maxWidth = 400;
         var lineHeight = 60;
         var x = 20; // (canvas.width - maxWidth) / 2;
         var y = 58;


         var text = document.getElementById("text").value.toUpperCase();                

         context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
         context.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 500);

         context.font = "51px 'LeagueGothicRegular'";
         context.fillStyle = "#333";

         wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
     }

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#text").keyup(function () {
             DrawText();
         });

     });

    </script>
```

Where `c` is the ID of my canvas and `text` is the ID of my textbox.

As you can probably see am using a non-standard font.  You can use @font-face as long as you have used the font on some text PRIOR to manipulating the canvas - otherwise the canvas won't pick up the font.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 32):

Split the text into lines, and draw each separately:

```
function fillTextMultiLine(ctx, text, x, y) {
  var lineHeight = ctx.measureText("M").width * 1.2;
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    ctx.fillText(lines[i], x, y);
    y += lineHeight;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's my solution, modifying the popular wrapText() function that is already presented here. I'm using the prototyping feature of JavaScript so that you can call the function from the canvas context.

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.wrapText = function (text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

    var lines = text.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

        var words = lines[i].split(' ');
        var line = '';

        for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
            var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
            var metrics = this.measureText(testLine);
            var testWidth = metrics.width;
            if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
                this.fillText(line, x, y);
                line = words[n] + ' ';
                y += lineHeight;
            }
            else {
                line = testLine;
            }
        }

        this.fillText(line, x, y);
        y += lineHeight;
    }
}
```

Basic usage:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "12px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.wrapText("Hello\nWorld!",20,20,160,16);
```

Here's a demonstration I put together:
http://jsfiddle.net/7RdbL/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

I just extended the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` adding two functions: mlFillText and mlStrokeText.

You can find the last version in [GitHub](https://github.com/jbaylina/jsTifier):

With this functions you can fill / stroke miltiline text in a box. You can align the text verticaly and horizontaly. (It  takes in account `\n`'s and can also justify the text).

The prototypes are:

```
function mlFillText(text,x,y,w,h,vAlign,hAlign,lineheight);
function mlStrokeText(text,x,y,w,h,vAlign,hAlign,lineheight);
```

Where `vAlign` can be: `top`, `center` or `button`

And `hAlign` can be: `left`, `center`, `right` or `justify`

You can test the lib here: http://jsfiddle.net/4WRZj/1/

[image]

Here is the code of the library:

```
// Library: mltext.js
// Desciption: Extends the CanvasRenderingContext2D that adds two functions: mlFillText and mlStrokeText.
//
// The prototypes are: 
//
// function mlFillText(text,x,y,w,h,vAlign,hAlign,lineheight);
// function mlStrokeText(text,x,y,w,h,vAlign,hAlign,lineheight);
// 
// Where vAlign can be: "top", "center" or "button"
// And hAlign can be: "left", "center", "right" or "justify"
// Author: Jordi Baylina. (baylina at uniclau.com)
// License: GPL
// Date: 2013-02-21

function mlFunction(text, x, y, w, h, hAlign, vAlign, lineheight, fn) {
    text = text.replace(/[\n]/g, " \n ");
    text = text.replace(/\r/g, "");
    var words = text.split(/[ ]+/);
    var sp = this.measureText(' ').width;
    var lines = [];
    var actualline = 0;
    var actualsize = 0;
    var wo;
    lines[actualline] = {};
    lines[actualline].Words = [];
    i = 0;
    while (i < words.length) {
        var word = words[i];
        if (word == "\n") {
            lines[actualline].EndParagraph = true;
            actualline++;
            actualsize = 0;
            lines[actualline] = {};
            lines[actualline].Words = [];
            i++;
        } else {
            wo = {};
            wo.l = this.measureText(word).width;
            if (actualsize === 0) {
                while (wo.l > w) {
                    word = word.slice(0, word.length - 1);
                    wo.l = this.measureText(word).width;
                }
                if (word === "") return; // I can't fill a single character
                wo.word = word;
                lines[actualline].Words.push(wo);
                actualsize = wo.l;
                if (word != words[i]) {
                    words[i] = words[i].slice(word.length, words[i].length);
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            } else {
                if (actualsize + sp + wo.l > w) {
                    lines[actualline].EndParagraph = false;
                    actualline++;
                    actualsize = 0;
                    lines[actualline] = {};
                    lines[actualline].Words = [];
                } else {
                    wo.word = word;
                    lines[actualline].Words.push(wo);
                    actualsize += sp + wo.l;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (actualsize === 0) lines[actualline].pop();
    lines[actualline].EndParagraph = true;

    var totalH = lineheight * lines.length;
    while (totalH > h) {
        lines.pop();
        totalH = lineheight * lines.length;
    }

    var yy;
    if (vAlign == "bottom") {
        yy = y + h - totalH + lineheight;
    } else if (vAlign == "center") {
        yy = y + h / 2 - totalH / 2 + lineheight;
    } else {
        yy = y + lineheight;
    }

    var oldTextAlign = this.textAlign;
    this.textAlign = "left";

    for (var li in lines) {
        var totallen = 0;
        var xx, usp;
        for (wo in lines[li].Words) totallen += lines[li].Words[wo].l;
        if (hAlign == "center") {
            usp = sp;
            xx = x + w / 2 - (totallen + sp * (lines[li].Words.length - 1)) / 2;
        } else if ((hAlign == "justify") && (!lines[li].EndParagraph)) {
            xx = x;
            usp = (w - totallen) / (lines[li].Words.length - 1);
        } else if (hAlign == "right") {
            xx = x + w - (totallen + sp * (lines[li].Words.length - 1));
            usp = sp;
        } else { // left
            xx = x;
            usp = sp;
        }
        for (wo in lines[li].Words) {
            if (fn == "fillText") {
                this.fillText(lines[li].Words[wo].word, xx, yy);
            } else if (fn == "strokeText") {
                this.strokeText(lines[li].Words[wo].word, xx, yy);
            }
            xx += lines[li].Words[wo].l + usp;
        }
        yy += lineheight;
    }
    this.textAlign = oldTextAlign;
}

(function mlInit() {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.mlFunction = mlFunction;

    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.mlFillText = function (text, x, y, w, h, vAlign, hAlign, lineheight) {
        this.mlFunction(text, x, y, w, h, hAlign, vAlign, lineheight, "fillText");
    };

    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.mlStrokeText = function (text, x, y, w, h, vAlign, hAlign, lineheight) {
        this.mlFunction(text, x, y, w, h, hAlign, vAlign, lineheight, "strokeText");
    };
})();
```

And here is the use example:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var T = "This is a very long line line with a CR at the end.\n This is the second line.\nAnd this is the last line.";
var lh = 12;

ctx.lineWidth = 1;

ctx.mlFillText(T, 10, 10, 100, 100, 'top', 'left', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 110, 10, 100, 100, 'top', 'center', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(110, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 210, 10, 100, 100, 'top', 'right', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(210, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 310, 10, 100, 100, 'top', 'justify', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(310, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 10, 110, 100, 100, 'center', 'left', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(10, 110, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 110, 110, 100, 100, 'center', 'center', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(110, 110, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 210, 110, 100, 100, 'center', 'right', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(210, 110, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 310, 110, 100, 100, 'center', 'justify', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(310, 110, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 10, 210, 100, 100, 'bottom', 'left', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(10, 210, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 110, 210, 100, 100, 'bottom', 'center', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(110, 210, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 210, 210, 100, 100, 'bottom', 'right', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(210, 210, 100, 100);

ctx.mlFillText(T, 310, 210, 100, 100, 'bottom', 'justify', lh);
ctx.strokeRect(310, 210, 100, 100);

ctx.mlStrokeText("Yo can also use mlStrokeText!", 0 , 310 , 420, 30, 'center', 'center', lh);
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Words is not defined` If i try to change font. For example: `ctx.font = '40px Arial';` - try putting that in your fiddle

Comment: Btw, where the hell does `Words` (case-sensitive) variable come from?? It's not defined anywhere. That part of the code only gets executed when you change font..

Comment: @psychobrm You are absolutly right. It is a bug (I already fix it). This part of code is only executed if you have to split a word in two lines. Thank you!

Comment: I've made some upgrades I needed: render spaces, render leading/trailing newlines, render stroke and fill with one call (dont measure text twice), I've also had to change iteration, since `for in` doesn't work well with extended `Array.prototype`. Could you put it on github so that we can iterate on it?

Comment: @psychobrm I merged your changes. Thank you!

Comment: how to set direction RTL for justify?

Comment: This library works very nicely, is small and simple, and has no dependencies.  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

I created a tiny library for this scenario here: [Canvas-Txt](https://github.com/geongeorge/Canvas-Txt)

It renders text in multi-line and it offers decent alignment modes.

[image]

In order to use this, you will need to either install it or use a CDN.

#### Installation

```
npm install canvas-txt --save
```

#### JavaScript

```js
import canvasTxt from 'canvas-txt'

var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')

var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'

canvasTxt.fontSize = 24

canvasTxt.drawText(ctx, txt, 100, 200, 200, 200)
```

This will render text in an invisible box with position/dimensions of:

```js
{ x: 100, y: 200, height: 200, width: 200 }
```

---

### Example Fiddle

```js
/* https://github.com/geongeorge/Canvas-Txt  */

const canvasTxt = window.canvasTxt.default;
const ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

const txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
const bounds = { width: 240, height: 80 };

let origin = { x: ctx.canvas.width / 2, y: ctx.canvas.height / 2, };
let offset = { x: origin.x - (bounds.width / 2), y: origin.y - (bounds.height / 2) };

canvasTxt.fontSize = 20;

ctx.fillStyle = '#C1A700';
ctx.fillRect(offset.x, offset.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);

ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
canvasTxt.drawText(ctx, txt, offset.x, offset.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

```css
body {
  background: #111;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #222; /* Could alternatively be painted on the canvas */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@2.0.6/build/index.js"></script>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="160"></canvas>
```

Comment: I went ahead and defined some variables to help "self-document" the example. It also handles centering the bounding box within the canvas. I also added a rectangle behind, so you can actually see it centered in relation. Great work! +1 One little thing I noticed is that the lines that wrap will not have their leading spaces suppressed. You may want to trim each line e.g. `ctx.fillText(txtline.trim(), textanchor, txtY)` I only noticed this in your interactive demo on your website.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thank you for clearing up the answer.
 I have fixed the trim issue and published the `2.0.9` version.
The demo site is fixed by updating the package version. There is an issue with multiple spaces. I do not know if it's better to go with an opinionated package or ignore the problem.  Been getting requests for this from multiple places. I went ahead and added trim anyway.
`Lorem ipsum dolor,        sit   <many spaces>     amet ` this was the reason why I didn't do it in the first place. 
What do you think should I consider multiple spaces and only remove if there is just one?

Comment: Edit: it seems StackOverflow code block ignores multi spaces as well

Answer (score 8):

Using javascript I developed a solution. It isn't beautiful but it worked for me:

---

```
function drawMultilineText(){

    // set context and formatting   
    var context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
    context.font = fontStyleStr;
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.textBaseline = "top";
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";

    // prepare textarea value to be drawn as multiline text.
    var textval = document.getElementByID("textarea").value;
    var textvalArr = toMultiLine(textval);
    var linespacing = 25;
    var startX = 0;
    var startY = 0;

    // draw each line on canvas. 
    for(var i = 0; i < textvalArr.length; i++){
        context.fillText(textvalArr[i], x, y);
        y += linespacing;
    }
}

// Creates an array where the <br/> tag splits the values.
function toMultiLine(text){
   var textArr = new Array();
   text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br/>');
   textArr = text.split("<br/>");
   return textArr;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: hello,suppose my text is like this  var text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; then what is happend in canvas???

Comment: It will go out of the canvas, as @Ramirez did not put the maxWidth parameter to fillText :)

Answer (score 7):

If you only need two lines of text, you can split them into two different fillText calls and give each one a different baseline.

```
ctx.textBaseline="bottom";
ctx.fillText("First line", x-position, y-position);
ctx.textBaseline="top";
ctx.fillText("Second line", x-position, y-position);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The code for word-wrapping (breaking at spaces) provided by [@Gaby Petrioli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478742/html5-canvas-can-i-somehow-use-linefeeds-in-filltext/4478894#4478894) is very helpful.
I've extended his code to provide support for newline characters `\n`. Also, often times it's useful to have the dimensions of the bounding box, so `multiMeasureText()` returns both the width and the height.

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffchan/WHgaY/76/

Comment: links expire, please put the code in this answer _even if_ you have a working link. If jsfiddle shuts down, this answer becomes entirely useless as is.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of Colin's `wrapText()` that also supports **vertically centered text** with `context.textBaseline = 'middle'`:

```
var wrapText = function (context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
    var paragraphs = text.split("\n");
    var textLines = [];

    // Loop through paragraphs
    for (var p = 0; p < paragraphs.length; p++) {
        var line = "";
        var words = paragraphs[p].split(" ");
        // Loop through words
        for (var w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
            var testLine = line + words[w] + " ";
            var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
            var testWidth = metrics.width;
            // Make a line break if line is too long
            if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
                textLines.push(line.trim());
                line = words[w] + " ";
            }
            else {
                line = testLine;
            }
        }
        textLines.push(line.trim());
    }

    // Move text up if centered vertically
    if (context.textBaseline === 'middle')
        y = y - ((textLines.length-1) * lineHeight) / 2;

    // Render text on canvas
    for (var tl = 0; tl < textLines.length; tl++) {
        context.fillText(textLines[tl], x, y);
        y += lineHeight;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This question isn't thinking in terms of how canvas works. If you want a line break just simply adjust the coordinates of your next `ctx.fillText`.

```
ctx.fillText("line1", w,x,y,z)
ctx.fillText("line2", w,x,y,z+20)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a well-maintained JS library called [Canvas-Txt](https://canvas-txt.geongeorge.com/#/) that is able to handle line breaks and text wrapping. I found it much more usable than all the random code snippets in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can still rely on CSS

```
ctx.measureText().height doesn’t exist.
```

Luckily, through CSS hack-ardry ( seeTypographic Metrics for more ways to fix older implementations of  using CSS measurements), we can find the height of the text through measuring the offsetHeight of a  with the same font-properties:

```
var d = document.createElement(”span”);
d.font = “20px arial”
d.textContent = “Hello world!”
var emHeight = d.offsetHeight;
```

from:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/texteffects/

Comment: That's a good solution if you have the memory to build an element like that every time you need to measure. You can also `ctx.save()` then, `ctx.font = '12pt Arial' ` then, `parseInt( ctx.font, 10 )`. Note that I use 'pt' when setting it. It then will translate into PX and be able to turn into a digit for consumption as the height of the font.

Answer (score 3):

I have created the [wraptext](https://github.com/quyettvq/wraptext) library that helps wrap text to fit the limitations of the view.

To wrap the text, we need to implement 2 logic:

- Line Fitting: Make sure no lines exceed the view width. This can be done by using Canvas API to measure the text width.
- Line Breaking: Make sure the lines are broken at the right positions (line break opportunities). This logic may be implemented differently, but it is better to follow this [Unicode's document](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/tr14-45.html) as it supports all languages.

Though this answer is too far from the moment the question was posted, I hope this will be helpful for those who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible neither, but a workaround for this is to create a `<p>`element and position it with Javascript.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking of doing. It's just that with `fillText()` and `strokeText()`, you can do things beyond what CSS can do.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I think this may be a better solution -- the other solutions here using fillText() make it so the text cannot be selected (or presumably pasted).

Answer (score 2):

I happened across this due to having the same problem.  I'm working with variable font size, so this takes that into account:

```
var texts=($(this).find('.noteContent').html()).split("<br>");
for (var k in texts) {
    ctx.fillText(texts[k], left, (top+((parseInt(ctx.font)+2)*k)));
}
```

where .noteContent is the contenteditable div the user edited (this is nested in a jQuery each function), and ctx.font is "14px Arial" (notice that the pixel size comes first)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function to draw multiple lines of text center in canvas (only break the line, don't break-word)

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let text = "Hello World \n Hello World 2222 \n AAAAA \n thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. "
ctx.font = "20px Arial";

fillTextCenter(ctx, text, 0, 0, c.width, c.height)

function fillTextCenter(ctx, text, x, y, width, height) {
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    const lines = text.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
    for(let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        let xL = (width - x) / 2
        let yL =  y + (height / (lines.length + 1)) * (i+1)

        ctx.fillText(lines[i], xL, yL)
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #000;"></canvas>
```

If you want to fit text size to canvas, you can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65433398/5381331)

Answer (score 0):

Canvas element doesn't support such characters as newline '\n', tab '\t' or < br /> tag.

Try it:

```
var newrow = mheight + 30;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.font = "bold 24px 'Verdana'";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Game Over", mwidth, mheight); //first line
ctx.fillText("play again", mwidth, newrow); //second line
```

or perhaps multiple lines:

```
var textArray = new Array('line2', 'line3', 'line4', 'line5');
var rows = 98;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
ctx.font = "bold 24px 'Verdana'";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Game Over", mwidth, mheight); //first line

for(var i=0; i < textArray.length; ++i) {
rows += 30;
ctx.fillText(textArray[i], mwidth, rows); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My ES5 solution for the problem:

```
var wrap_text = (ctx, text, x, y, lineHeight, maxWidth, textAlign) => {
  if(!textAlign) textAlign = 'center'
  ctx.textAlign = textAlign
  var words = text.split(' ')
  var lines = []
  var sliceFrom = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var chunk = words.slice(sliceFrom, i).join(' ')
    var last = i === words.length - 1
    var bigger = ctx.measureText(chunk).width > maxWidth
    if(bigger) {
      lines.push(words.slice(sliceFrom, i).join(' '))
      sliceFrom = i
    }
    if(last) {
      lines.push(words.slice(sliceFrom, words.length).join(' '))
      sliceFrom = i
    }
  }
  var offsetY = 0
  var offsetX = 0
  if(textAlign === 'center') offsetX = maxWidth / 2
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillText(lines[i], x + offsetX, y + offsetY)
    offsetY = offsetY + lineHeight
  }
}
```

More information on the issue is [on my blog](http://olegberman.com/simple-algorithm-to-wrap-text-in-html5-canvas/).