# If/Then Javascript to Display HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, if-statement

I have some html5 and javascript code to create a spinning roulette wheel. It is split up into 14 outcomes. My question is, how can I get some unique HTML code to display per each outcome of the wheel. For example, if the wheel lands on Business, some text will appear below the wheel that has information on Business.

Here is my HTML code and below it is a link to a working example:

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/1010/source/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<input type="button" value="spin" onclick="spin();" style="float: left;" />
<canvas id="wheelcanvas" width="800" height="750"></canvas>
<script type="application/javascript">
  var colors = ["#B8D430", "#3AB745", "#029990", "#3501CB",
               "#2E2C75", "#673A7E", "#CC0071", "#F80120",
               "#F35B20", "#FB9A00", "#FFCC00", "#FEF200", "#B2DF00", "#5C8300"];
  var classes = ["Business", "Office Education", "Continuing Care Assistant", "Practical Nursing",
                     "Primary Care Paramedic", "Early Childhood Education", "Cooking", "Electrician",
                     "Heavy Equipment Operator", "Industrial Mechanic - Millwright", "Plumbing & Pipefitting", "Truck Driver Training", "Welding", "Power Engineering"];

  var startAngle = 0;
  var arc = Math.PI / 7;
  var spinTimeout = null;

  var spinArcStart = 10;
  var spinTime = 0;
  var spinTimeTotal = 0;

  var ctx;

  function draw() {
    drawRouletteWheel();
  }

  function drawRouletteWheel() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("wheelcanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var outsideRadius = 300;
      var textRadius = 260;
      var insideRadius = 100;

      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(5,0,1000,1000);


      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;

      ctx.font = 'bold 10px sans-serif';

      for(var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(400, 400, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
        ctx.arc(400, 400, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = -1;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = -1;
        ctx.shadowBlur    = 0;
        ctx.shadowColor   = "rgb(220,220,220)";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.translate(400 + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius, 400 + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
        ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
        var text = classes[i];
        ctx.fillText(text, -ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      } 

      //Arrow
      ctx.fillStyle = "black";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(400 - 4, 400 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 + 4, 400 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 + 4, 400 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 + 9, 400 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 + 0, 400 - (outsideRadius - 13));
      ctx.lineTo(400 - 9, 400 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 - 4, 400 - (outsideRadius - 5));
      ctx.lineTo(400 - 4, 400 - (outsideRadius + 5));
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }

  function spin() {
    spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    spinTime = 0;
    spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000;
    rotateWheel();
  }

  function rotateWheel() {
    spinTime += 30;
    if(spinTime >= spinTimeTotal) {
      stopRotateWheel();
      return;
    }
    var spinAngle = spinAngleStart - easeOut(spinTime, 0, spinAngleStart, spinTimeTotal);
    startAngle += (spinAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    drawRouletteWheel();
    spinTimeout = setTimeout('rotateWheel()', 30);
  }

  function stopRotateWheel() {
    clearTimeout(spinTimeout);
    var degrees = startAngle * 180 / Math.PI + 90;
    var arcd = arc * 180 / Math.PI;
    var index = Math.floor((360 - degrees % 360) / arcd);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
    var text = classes[index]
    ctx.fillText(text, 400 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 400 + 10);
    ctx.restore();
    document.getElementById('wheelResult').innerHTML = 'Test' + text;
  }

  function easeOut(t, b, c, d) {
    var ts = (t/=d)*t;
    var tc = ts*t;
    return b+c*(tc + -3*ts + 3*t);
  }

  draw();
</script>

<p id="wheelResult"></p>
```

http://www.ctrc.sk.ca/wheel.html

Comment: Your page works fine and your question is already implemented, what is the problem?

Comment: It works fine yes but I am having trouble implementing unique text popping up per different wheel outcome. For instance, if the wheel lands on business it brings up business yes, but it is taking that from the javascript within the wheel. I need it to pull up html code later in the page that has a specific description relating to business, not just the word business.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it but this is the way I would do it.
You could create a div tag with the css style of display:none and then set it with the info desired and hide and show it as needed.

Example:

```
<script>
    var htmlData = ['<h1>Business</h1><br><span>What is Business?</span><br>...', ...];
    ....
    function spin()
    {
        //Hide description box.
        document.getElementById('idDescriptionBox').style.display = 'none';

        spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
        ....
    }
    ....
    function stopRotateWheel()
    {
        ....
        //Set description and display it.
        var descriptionBox = document.getElementById('idDescriptionBox');
        descriptionBox.innerHTML = htmlData[index];
        descriptionBox.style.display = 'block';
    }
    ....
</script>
<div id="idDescriptionBox" style="display:none;">
    <!--Description info in here-->
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried embedding this into my code and the page stopped working.

Will this display unique text for each different wheel outcome? For instance if they land on business it will bring up business information, and if they land on plumbing it will bring up different plumbing information?

Comment: @JeremyBritz It depends upon what values you put into the htmlData variable.  Put the different data that relates to the possible outcomes at the correct indices of that variable, and they will be correctly unique to each outcome.  Not sure why it's not working.  Going to do more looking at it.

Comment: @JeremyBritz  I tested it and the only thing I can think of that may cause it not to work is if you copied the *htmlData* variable as is and didn't finish the line.  You need to insert all of the correct data into *htmlData* like you have for *classes* variable.

Comment: One more question, is there any way to add line breaks to the text on the wheel?

Comment: @JeremyBritz  I think [this answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026961/html5-canvas-ctx-filltext-wont-do-line-breaks) will be of help to you.  Just note the line that inserts that text is *ctx.fillText(text, 400 - ctx.measureText(text).width / 2, 400 + 10);*