# Next line(line break) for Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how do i put a "next line" for a variable that has multiple items in Javascript. 
Do i put \ or \n or  \r\n or an html line break  in this line?

This is the code:

```
 var html = "Title : " + data[i].title + "   description \r\n  : " + data[i].description +  "\n"; 



 var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,(rectSize+100)*i,250,80);
           ctx.fillText(html, 20,(rectSize+120)*i);
ctx.stroke();
```

I am trying to put 2 items in a variable that is going through a loop and i want the items to be in different lines. Or do i have to assign different variables to each item?

Comment: Do you want this newline to appear in an HTML rendered page (browser) or the console?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your HTML variable is populating a `pre` element, HTML documents will ignore the `\r` and `\n` escape characters anyway. You can instead use [the `br` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element):

```
var html = "..." + ... "... <br>" + ... ;
```

Comment: @AmitJoki `<br>` is fine as it is if it's HTML and not XHTML.

Comment: I tried putting in <br> but it is just displaying <br> as text tho in the html, its not breaking the line

Comment: @Clarklight how are you adding it? You need to use `innerHTML`, not `innerText`, for instance.

Comment: I am adding it in ctx.filltext

Comment: @Clarklight that completely changes the context of the question. You should specify things like this at the beginning. My answer is now worthless and this question is now a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026961/html5-canvas-ctx-filltext-wont-do-line-breaks

Comment: ooo sorry i didnt know that, this is the first time i am working on this

Comment: I am just trying to display a few texts that through a loop, is ctx the only way to do so? Or is there any other ways? I am just trying to loop through some data, and put each set of data into a rectangle box for display.

Comment: @Clarklight I don't know enough about developing with Canvas to be able to help I'm afraid. I believe the question I've linked you to should be able to answer your question though.