# HTML5 Canvas - repeat text all the canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to draw inside a cavnas all the size of it? I've checked that I can repeat an image but I just want to repeat a text.

As a plus, if it the text could be shifted each line, could be great. Example of the effect I need if i set "1234567" as text:

```
1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567
234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 
34567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1
4567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 12
567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 123
67 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234
7 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 12345
 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 123456
1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567 1234567
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`measureText(txt)`**

You can measure text with canvas

```
canvas.measureText(txt).width
```

Here is a basic example with various limitations. Some more math is needed to create bigger canvases...

`txtHeight` is basically line-height. `offset` is the distance you want to shift the text.

The rest is math which should be improved for a solid function.

**Code**

```js
var b = document.createElement('canvas');
b.width = 320;
b.height = 160;
c = b.getContext("2d");

function draw(txt) {
  c.font = "20px Arial";
  var txtHeight = 25;
  var offset = 5;
  var w = Math.ceil(c.measureText(txt).width);
  var txt = new Array(w * 2).join(txt + ' '); //change the multipler for more lines
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(b.height / txtHeight); i++) {
    c.fillText(txt, -(i * offset), i * txtHeight);
  }
}
document.body.appendChild(b);
draw('1234567');
```

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/wav0xmLz/1/

For more precision measuring every line or writing letter per letter would be better.

**EDIT**

Unless you use a **monospaced font** it's a mess to remove the half visible txt....as every letter has different spacing. `iiii` is always shorter than `TTTT` with non monospaced fonts.

[monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) have a fixed spacing .... find that and you know exactly how width every charachter is ... do some math and your done.

You can then use `split,shift,join,push` to create then each line

https://jsfiddle.net/kds7zkkf/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer. Just the first part.

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.wrapText = function (text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

  var lines = text.split("\n");

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    var words = lines[i].split(' ');
    var line = '';

    for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
      var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
      var metrics = this.measureText(testLine);
      var testWidth = metrics.width;
      if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
        this.fillText(line, x, y);
        line = words[n] + ' ';
        y += lineHeight;
      } else {
        line = testLine;
      }
    }

    this.fillText(line, x, y);
    y += lineHeight;
  }
};



var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "12px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  str += '1234567 ';
}
ctx.wrapText(str,0,0,myCanvas.width,16);
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

References: [HTML5 canvas ctx.fillText won't do line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026961/html5-canvas-ctx-filltext-wont-do-line-breaks#17777674)