# Line break in a javascript html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, line-breaks

I've made an HTML canvas, and I would like to put a break in the canvas text after the username variable  but it is not recognizing the line breaks I have tried so far e.g `\n` or `<br />`. This is the code

```
function drawText() {
  let startText = "Welcome "+username+"You've answered "+questionCount+" out of 10";
  ctx.font = '30px Calibri';//size and type of font
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f0f0f0";//colour of font
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText(startText, 350, 350);
}

window.addEventListener("load", drawText(), false);
```

Comment: where did you define `ctx` ? ... please enter the code completely.

Comment: I think your question has been asked before... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026961/html5-canvas-ctx-filltext-wont-do-line-breaks