# Javascript canvas: full (justify) alignment

Tags: javascript, canvas, alignment

In MDN documentation and in previous questions in SO, there are no mentioning about full (justify) alignment.

Anyone have the same problem and already have the solution?

PS: there are previous related question to this topic, but there's no correct / accepted answer.

Related question: [How to justify align text in html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517999/how-to-justify-align-text-in-html5-canvas)

Example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  context.font = "18px sans-serif";
  context.textAlign = "full"; //the question: this option doesn't exist
  context.fillText("The Text", 50, 50);
};
img.src = imagePath; //note: change it with real image URL or image URI
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm using https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image to solve this problem. I just need to "draw" everything in HTML & CSS, then convert it to image.

Example (from their website, which I use with some proper edit):

```
var node = document.getElementById('my-node');

domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
```